# SQL Server column was specified multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    table12.* 
from 
    (select *
     from [Crimes].[FactCrimes] as fact
     inner join [Crimes].[DimCrimeClassification] as crime on fact.CrimeTypeID = crime.CrimeTypeID
     where[Index Code] = 'i') as table12;
```

but I keep getting this error:

> The column 'CrimeTypeID' was specified multiple times for 'table12'

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: I knew about the error but I have been working so hard that my mind was freeze. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use/specify column names in derived table instead of *.  CrimeTypeID is present in both the tables and hence available twice in that query. Always use column names to avoid these kind of errors and better performance

Comment: @cookiemonster . . . Then you should accept this answer, if you think it is correct.